# When I get a value from a registry key I get System.Byte[]

Tags: c#, registry, output

In C#, I'm trying to obtain the value of a registry key. It is a binary key. The code I'm using

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
            regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Wow6432Node\Bohemia Interactive Studio\ArmA 2 OA\");

            if (regKey != null)
            {
                string value = regKey.GetValue("KEY").ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
```

When it writes to the console, all it outputs is `System.Byte[]`. How can I output the exact value of the key? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You just cast to `byte[]` to get the value since your value is binary:

```
byte[] value = (byte[])regKey.GetValue("KEY");
```

To display binary, you can display in two hexadecimal digits:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
     Console.Write(" {0:X2}", value[i]);
```

Comment: @Decker Thus your code should not compile as you are assigning an object to a string without a cast

Answer (score 0):

The value you get from `regKey.GetValue("KEY")` might be a byte array.

Please consider convert it to HEX like [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)